# How to copy a file from Unix AIX server to nas drive on windows server?

Tags: windows, unix

The is nas drive created on window server and it is named as: nas1234dc.
The is a folder under \nas1234dc\data\sourcefile. To access this sourcefile, my user need to be added to a group and that group is having access to this directory. I have username and password of the same.
Now I am on Unix AIX server and trying to connect to nas drive which is on windows as below:

```
set -x; 
HOST='nas1234dc'    
USER='winuser'    
PASSWD='winpwd'    
ftp -i -n $HOST <<EOF    
user ${USER} ${PASSWD}    
binary    
cd C:\    
put testing.txt    
quit      
EOF  

Response while running this script is: ftp: connect: Connection refused
```

Could any one of us help me whether I am in correct root to copy the file to nas drive? Do I have any other best option to copy it securely?

Thanks,
Venkat

Comment: To use the `ftp` protocol you need an FTP server. But the old, outdated and insecure `ftp` protocol should not be used any more anyway. So either you can directly mount that NAS drive in your unixoid system and the use plain file access methods, or you need to export the volume via the MS-Windows system as `smb` share, the  you can access it using an `smb` client which is available for unixoid environments.

Comment: Well, samba can be compiled on AIX, but it is not entirely trivial. AIX doesn't have smbfs/cifs file-system so you cannot mount shares, but program `smbclient` is usable.